# Посоветуйте книгу по j2EE

Tags: java-ee, книги

По java SE добывал знания по Эккелю, но больше понравился Блинов (меньше воды и книга как по мне серьезнее). И вот решил заняться j2ee. Желательно на русском. + буду скорее всего приобретать в бумаге, так как от монитора уже глаза вылазят.

P.S. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Я рекомендую начать с [этого](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) и [этого](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/java/j2ee.php). А потом уже читать умные книжки. Есть 
подборка книг по j2ee. Выбирайте ту, которая больше всего понравится. Поищите по названиям на ресурсах.

1. Ajax on Java
2. Beginning Java EE 5 From Novice to Professional
3. Core J2EE Patterns Best Practices and Design Strategies, Second Edition
4. Expert One-on-One J2EE Development without EJB
5. Foundations of AOP for J2EE Development
6. J2EE AntiPatterns
7. J2EE Design Patterns
8. J2EE Developer's Handbook
9. J2EE Professional Projects
10. J2EE Security for Servlets, EJBs, and Web Services
11. Java 2 Enterprise Edition 1.4 Bible
12. Java Enterprise in a Nutshell, Third Edition
13. Rapid J2EE Development An Adaptive Foundation for Enterprise Applications
14. Sams Teach Yourself J2EE in 21 Days
15. The J2EE Architect's Handbook
16. The Java EE 5 Tutorial, Third Edition

Answer (score 0):

Алур Дипак "Образцы J2EE. Лучшие решения и стратегии проектирования"